# Unknown VM Pauses

Tags: io, garbage-collection, virtual-machine

In my KVM, having 4 to 5 VMs. At Certain stage faced request failures. While checking GC logs, suddenly all application threads were stopped for certain times (~1sec). During that time, When checking in KVM, other VMs heavily used I/O threads.

On further checking in google, found this happened due to IO thread heavy usage. When one GC(Garbage Collection) ran in a VM and it wants to write the gc logs but the io thread in the KVM was busy and process the other VMs data. On that time, application threads are not released from the safe point until the gc log write completly.

Refer link: [Eliminating Large JVM GC Pauses Caused by Background IO Traffic](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2016/02/eliminating-large-jvm-gc-pauses-caused-by-background-io-traffic#:%7E:text=SSD%20can%20be%20adopted%20as%20a%20dedicated%20drive%20for%20GC%20logging%2C%20or%20shared%20with%20other%20IO%20loads.)

Is anyone experience this issue? Can someone have any other solution to handle this problem.